# how to import whole instance of oracle database to another instance with tablespaces and datefiles

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

when i am importing whole database instance to another database instance in oracle, only temp tables have been imported others table are not imported to the new instance, these tables are in user defined tablespace. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you can try and [duplicate using rman](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2.php). tip : check the prerequisites first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Database copy option in SQL Developer.